# Import image from Excel sheet into SQL Server table C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

Here I want to insert all the data from my excel sheet into the `SQL Server` Table using C# code

I have the Excel sheet with data like this

```
ID    Name    Designation    ProfilePicture
--------------------------------------------
1    ABC      Manager        C:\Pictures\1.jpg
2    DEF      Asst.Manager   C:\Pictures\2.jpg
```

And I have the Code to Insert the Datas into the Table

```
String filePath = filePathText.Text;
String fileExtension = "Excel 12.0";
if (filePath != null)
{
    String xlsConnection = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=" + "\"" + fileExtension + ";HDR=YES;\"";

    String sqlConnection = "Your Connection String";

    //Connection to Excel work book
    OleDbConnection xlsConnectionString = new OleDbConnection(xlsConnection);

    //Fetch data from Excel
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select [ID],[Name],[Designation],[ProfilePicture] from [Sheet1$]", xlsConnectionString);

    xlsConnectionString.Open();

    OleDbDataReader dReader;
    dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection);

    //Destination table name
    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "EXCEL_DATA";

    sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);

    xlsConnectionString.Close();
}
```

This piece of code is run, if I click the button.

My Question is, How can I upload the picture from Excel Sheet (Sheet have the path of the image). to `SQL Server` Table. I want to get the picture by using the Imagepath provided in Excel Sheet and store it as `varbinary(MAX)` in `SQL Server`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the guys who really works to post the answer. Finally I got the solution to the problem myself.

Here is the code that helps to insert the images into the `SQL Server` by using the Path provided in `Excel sheet`.

```
    private void insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        UInt64 ID = 0;
        String Name = String.Empty;
        String Designation = String.Empty;
        String ProfilePicture = String.Empty;

        String filePath = filePathText.Text;

        Excel.Application xlApp = null;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = null;
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = null;
        Excel.Range xlRange = null;

        String sqlConnectionString = "Your Connection String goes here";

        String insertRecord = "INSERT_USER_RECORDS";

        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(insertRecord, sqlConnection);
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        sqlConnection.Open();

        if (filePath != null)
        {

            try
            {

                xlApp = new Excel.Application();
                xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
                xlWorksheet = (Excel._Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
                xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

                int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
                int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

                for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
                {
                    for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show((xlRange.Cells[row, col] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2.ToString());

                        // Check xlRange for Every run. And assign values to local variables. Here I just show the values using MsgBox

                        // If you get the Path of Image then call the function to Convert Image into byte

                        // Convert Image to Byte Function definition.

                        /* System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(ProfilePicture, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
                           Byte[] imageAsBytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
                           fs.Read(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.Length);
                           fs.Close();
                           return imageAsBytes; */

                    }

                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Clear();
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = FirstName;
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Designation", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = LastName;
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ProfilePicture", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = imageAsBytes;
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = ID;

                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }


                MessageBox.Show(Path.GetFileName(filePath) + "is Successfully imported to SQL Server", "Result", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                //Release All objects and close the Connection to prevent the Excel file from lock.

                sqlConnection.Close();

                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlRange);
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);

                xlWorkbook.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);

                xlApp.Quit();
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlApp);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select the Valid file to import");
        }
    }
```

This code works fine and helps me to insert the image into the `SQL` database from `Excel`.
No matter about the version of excel file.